# pseudo element body border

Tags: html, css, border, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create a body border for my site that has a gap near the top for the logo, yet is completely closed at the bottom. I can only seem to do one or the other.

Here is what I am looking for, [Body Border example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUB5D.jpg):

[image: Body Border example]

Here's the approach I've been taking. A simple body wrapper with before/after psuedo elements.
HTML

```
 <html>
 <body>
   <div class="borderWrap>
     <header> Logo resides here </header>
     <main> content goes here </main>
   </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

CSS

```
  .borderWrap{position: relative; }

    .borderWrap:after, .borderWrap:before {
        border: 0.125em solid ; 
        bottom: 20px;    
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 35px;
        width: 40.5%;
        bottom: -50px;
        }

    .borderWrap:after {
        border-left: none;
        right: 40px;
        }

    .borderWrap:before {
        border-right: none;
        left: 40px;
        }
```

This gives me a dynamic border as I need, but it still leaves a gap at the bottom. How do I go about closing it? Should I use a different method alltogether?

Comment: why can't you just apply a normal border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken a different approach of just applying a regular border to 'borderWrap' and centering the header within it, then applying a negative top margin and a solid white background.

https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/xvhb4kuf/

```
.borderWrap {
    position: relative;
    margin:35px auto 20px;
    width:81%;
    border: 0.125em solid;
}
header {
    width:80px;
    background:#fff;
    margin:-20px auto 0;
}
```

Comment: I wish I would have thought of this earlier. I used your idea combined with what I already had to get what I wanted. I just filled the gap completely by changing the width in my orig. code to 50%, and then used your white BG idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it using pseudo-elements.

You can control the width of the white-gap using `calc(50% + 40px)` for example, where `40px` is the half-width of the desired gap width, using
this value for the left and right offsets for the absolute positioned pseudo elements.

You could simplify things by simply using a percentage value for the offsets in case you don't want to use the CSS `calc` function.

The advantage of this approach is that if you have any background colors or images, they will show through the gap in the top border.

In my example, I illustrate how to create the border.  How you will use it in your layout will depend on how you build your page, but the approach is the same.

```css
.borderWrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-top-width: 0;
}
.borderWrap:before, .borderWrap:after {
  content: '\A0';
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.borderWrap:before {
  left: 0;
  right: calc(50% + 40px);
}
.borderWrap:after {
  right: 0;
  left: calc(50% + 40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="borderWrap"></div>
```

Comment: This is a great way of doing it had I done this from the get go. It was an easier fix with what I already to use the white background suggestion above. I didn't know about the calc function, that will be really useful. Thank you for this.